# Proposal for local data declarations / instances

Tags: haskell, local, typeclass

I'm curious, and have been unable to find a proposal for something like this in Haskell.  Consider if `sort` had been written but not `sortBy`.

```
sortBy :: forall a. (a -> a -> Ordering) -> [a] -> [a]
sortBy f = map getX . sort . map X
    where
    newtype X = X { getX :: a }
    instance Ord X where
        compare (X a) (X b) = f a b
```

Has anyone seen this proposal?

Comment: For what it's worth, you can achieve this with the [reflection](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/reflection) functional pearl/package; see [this example](https://github.com/ekmett/reflection/blob/master/examples/Monoid.hs). (Full disclosure: I have commits in the package.)

Comment: As much as I love this idea (and have wanted the same thing in the past), I'm not sure this is a real question...

Comment: I'm not proposing; I was fairly sure it would have been proposed before but I couldn't find it.  An acceptable answer would be one that points to a discussion of this or a similar proposal, or one from someone involved in this aspect of the community saying "I haven't seen one; here are some related things though."  Does that constitute a real question?

Comment: @luqui: I suppose so, but you could do with clarifying this in the question a little – your title is certainly a little misleading :)

Answer (score 1):

Apparently, local instances have been discussed briefly at Haskell Prime mailing list: http://web.archiveorange.com/archive/v/eKcS7T2qBpy7czBE2Jei, and more fully in the 6<sup>th</sup> chapter of Oleg’s paper “Functional Pearl: Implicit Conﬁgurations”. I have heard practically nothing about local data declarations, though.